# How do I import Pandas on Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, pandas, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

When I call:

```
import pandas as pd
```

on `tensorflow_macos` (for M1 chip)

I get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     28 try:
---> 29     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
     30 except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover

~/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py in <module>
     12 
---> 13 from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
     14 from pandas._libs.tslibs import (

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ashkan/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/ashkan/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/ashkan/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-94f55571b0d6> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 

~/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     31     # hack but overkill to use re
     32     module = str(e).replace("cannot import name ", "")
---> 33     raise ImportError(
     34         f"C extension: {module} not built. If you want to import "
     35         "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "

ImportError: C extension: dlopen(/Users/ashkan/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/ashkan/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/ashkan/tensorflow_macos_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-38-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

Comment: Check the feed-back: ... 'but wrong architecture not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.' , have you tried to import from source, and run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' like it suggested?

Comment: Yes, I saw that. run 'python setup.py build_ext --force'  where (which location)?
Pandas folder under TensorFlow_macos doesn't have a setup.py.

Answer (score 7):

I hope Xcode Command Line Tools is already installed. If not, please install it then follow the steps.

**Step 1:miniforge**

Install miniforge for arm64 (Apple Silicon) from [miniforge GitHub](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge). Miniforge enables installing python packages natively compiled for Apple Silicon.

**Step 2: create Conda environment**

*Don’t forget to open a new session or to source your .zshrc after miniforge install and before going through this step.*

Create an empty Conda environment, then activate it and install python 3.8. and all the needed packages. Please note numpy is unnecessary here as pandas already install it, but it will be overwritten in the last step with the version provided by Apple.

```
conda create --name mytf
conda activate mytf
conda install -y python==3.8.6
conda install -y pandas matplotlib scikit-learn jupyterlab
```

I have tested it. It will work after these steps.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the next post(https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/6), it seems that the solution is to install pandas from conda until they fix this problem.

To install pandas:

```
conda install pandas
```

Or installing directly from the source:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#installation-from-sources

Comment: Thanks Enrique. Does Conda know about M1? I can only see x64 & x86 Mac installers.

Comment: @Ashkan you can use x64.

Comment: it didn't work. it complained about the architecture

Comment: @Ashkan Use miniforge https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps -
Important [With Tensorflow Installation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)

With miniforge installation do this -

```py
conda install numpy scipy scikit-learn pandas matplotlib seaborn
```

Comment: - Before doing this please do the full installation procedure using https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ link

Answer (score -1):

Use Anaconda visual UI to install into the conda environment you created. You just select your environment and search for pandas.